# Spring ThreadPoolTaskExecutor configuration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, java-ee-6, quartz-scheduler

i am using Spring 2.5 `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` as below.

```
<bean id="taskExecutor"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="5" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
    <property name="WaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown" value="true" />
</bean>
```

### java code:

```
ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = (ThreadPoolTaskExecutor) context.getBean("taskExecutor");
    taskExecutor.execute(new PrintTask("Thread 1"));
    taskExecutor.execute(new PrintTask("Thread 2"));
    taskExecutor.execute(new PrintTask("Thread 3"));
    taskExecutor.execute(new PrintTask("Thread 4"));
    taskExecutor.execute(new PrintTask("Thread 5"));
```

Above code works fine without any issues. My problem is, `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`  is asynchronous, it means it does not wait till the task gets completed. It just fires and forgets. If any of the execute call throws any exception I need to catch it and send an email.

In order to do so, how can I make the process wait till taskExecutor's execute methods gets completed to know whether it throws any exceptions or not?

Also, what is `WaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown` in my configuration?

When can i call `taskExecutor.shutdown();`?  Please help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could call submit() rather than execute() and get a Future back, which would tell you if there was an error; the downside of this is you have to make a blocking call to find the error.

A better (or at least, more asynchronous) solution is to handle the error within your PrintTask:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        doPrintTaskStuff();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        sendEmailAboutException(t);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. is Future and submit() available in spring 2.5 ?

Comment: Hmm actually it looks like it's not. Is there any reason you can't use the latest Spring version (3.2.4 at the time of writing)?

Comment: OK, then maybe try the solution I mentioned, handling the error case in the task itself

Comment: what does taskExecutor.shutdown(); do here? does it wait till all threads completes the process?

Comment: After calling shutdown() you won't be able to add any more tasks. If you call setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true) first (which you have already done in your XML config), then yes it will wait until all threads are finished. What it won't do is give you any information on whether those tasks succeeded or failed, so you still need to handle that yourself.

Comment: i am using same taskExecutor for multiple jobs. consider i have two jobs say job1 and job2. both the jobs uses same taskExecutor. In that case if i shut down taskExecutor in job1 then will it not affect job2 ? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36853/discussion-between-tom-mcintyre-and-user755806)

Comment: I have to solve the similar task. I use execute, not submit. If I have any error , for this, i have try-cache - as it was written above. I also have whilte(true) { if(executor.getActiveCount()==0)  executor.shutdown() } is it good way? Because of WaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown=true task never will be shut down automatically. Is there any another solution?